# How to insert the selected data from drop down menu into multiple table in database

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

**This is my register.php (form):**

```
<table width="350" border="0">
  <center><tr>
    <td><form action="newregister.php" method="post">
    Nama</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td width="200"><center><input name="nama_pelajar" type="text"></center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No Kad Pengenalan</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><center><input name="ic_pelajar" type="text"></center></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ID Pelajar</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><center><input name="id_pelajar" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><br>Sesi</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><center><select name="sesi">
      <option><center>-Sila pilih-</option>
      <option value="Jun 14">Jun 2014</option>
      <option value="Dis 14">Dis 2014</option>
      <option value="Jun 15">Jun 2015</option>
      <option value="Dis 15">Dis 2015</option>
      <option value="Jun 16">Jun 2016</option>
      <option value="Dis 16">Dis 2016</option>
      <option value="Jun 17">Jun 2017</option>
      <option value="Dis 17">Dis 2017</option>
      </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><br>Kursus</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><center><select name="kursus">
      <option>-Sila pilih-</option>
      <option value="Senibina">Kursus Lukisan Seni Bina</option>
      <option value="Elektrik">Kursus Pemasangan Elektrik</option>
      <option value="Fesyen">Kursus Fesyen &amp; Pakaian</option>
      <option value="Makanan">Kursus Pemprosesan Makanan</option>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><br>No Telefon</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><center><input name="no_tel" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><br>Email</td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><center><input name="email" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><center><input name="" type="submit" value="Simpan">
  <input name="" type="reset" value="Set Semula">
  </center>
  </form>

  </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

**and this is my php code (newregister.php):**

```
<?php

require_once "conn.php";
    $conn = connect();
    $db = connectdb();
mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die (mysql_error() . "\n");

$query_usr = "select * from register_jun14";
$usr = mysql_query($query_usr,$conn) or die(mysql_error()."\n".$query_usr);
$row_usr=mysql_fetch_assoc($usr);

$nama_pelajar=$_REQUEST["nama_pelajar"];
$ic_pelajar=$_REQUEST["ic_pelajar"];
$id_pelajar=$_REQUEST["id_pelajar"];
$sesi=$_REQUEST["sesi"];
$kursus=$_REQUEST["kursus"];
$no_tel=$_REQUEST["no_tel"];
$email=$_REQUEST["email"];

$query = "INSERT INTO register_jun14(nama_pelajar,ic_pelajar,id_pelajar,sesi,kursus,no_tel,email) VALUES ('$nama_pelajar','$ic_pelajar',
'$id_pelajar','$sesi','$kursus','$no_tel','$email')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<script languange = 'Javascript'>
                alert('Pendaftaran berjaya!');
                location.href = 'register.php';</script>";

?>
```

**My question:**

How to insert selected **"sesi"** (drop down menu) into new table in database if there have table for "Jun14","Dis14","Jun15","Dis15" and so on ?

Anyone?

Comment: what do you mean by table for "Jun14","Dis14","Jun15","Dis15" and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to choose the table (means you have multiple table jun14, dis14, jun15 and so on)according to your drop down selection in this box

```
<td><center><select name="sesi">
      <option><center>-Sila pilih-</option>
      <option value="Jun 14">Jun 2014</option>
      <option value="Dis 14">Dis 2014</option>
      <option value="Jun 15">Jun 2015</option>
      <option value="Dis 15">Dis 2015</option>
      <option value="Jun 16">Jun 2016</option>
      <option value="Dis 16">Dis 2016</option>
      <option value="Jun 17">Jun 2017</option>
      <option value="Dis 17">Dis 2017</option>
      </select>
     </td>
```

first you need to change the above part like this

```
//you should remove the space and add underscore in order for your query to work
//for the if statement
<td><center><select name="sesi">
      <option><center>-Sila pilih-</option>
      <option value="jun_14">Jun 2014</option>
      <option value="dec_14">Dis 2014</option>
      <option value="Jun_15">Jun 2015</option>
      <option value="Dis_15">Dis 2015</option>
      <option value="Jun_16">Jun 2016</option>
      <option value="Dis_16">Dis 2016</option>
      <option value="Jun_17">Jun 2017</option>
      <option value="Dis_17">Dis 2017</option>
      </select>
     </td>
```

i removed the space in the value and added a underscore like jun 14 become jun_14, dec 14 become dec _14 and so on,

now your newregister php should look like this

```
 <?php
//i remove your this line assuming these lines you are connecting with your database these lines i removed
//require_once "conn.php";
 //$conn = connect();
 //   $db = connectdb();
//mysql_select_db($db,$conn) or die (mysql_error() . "\n");

        //and i added this line instead in this line i am also connecting 
//with database
    $conn=  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'yourpassword', 'yourdatabasename') 
or   die(mysqli_error($con));



    $query_usr = "select * from register_jun14";
    //$usr = mysql_query($query_usr,$conn) or die(mysql_error()."\n".$query_usr);

    $usr = mysqli_query($conn,$query_usr) or die(mysqli_error()."\n".$query_usr);
    $row_usr=mysqli_fetch_assoc($usr);

    $nama_pelajar=$_REQUEST["nama_pelajar"];
    $ic_pelajar=$_REQUEST["ic_pelajar"];
    $id_pelajar=$_REQUEST["id_pelajar"];
    $sesi=$_REQUEST["sesi"];
    $kursus=$_REQUEST["kursus"];
    $no_tel=$_REQUEST["no_tel"];
    $email=$_REQUEST["email"];


    if($sesi=="jun_14")
    {
    //assuming you have Jun14 table in your database with same field as your 
    //original  insert query in the question

        $query = "INSERT INTO  Jun14(id, nama_pelajar,ic_pelajar,id_pelajar,sesi,kursus,no_tel,email) VALUES ('','$nama_pelajar','$ic_pelajar',
    '$id_pelajar','$sesi','$kursus','$no_tel','$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    if($sesi=="dec_14")
    {
    //assuming you have Dis14 table in your database with same field as your 
        //original insert query in the question

        $query = "INSERT INTO  Dis14(id, nama_pelajar,ic_pelajar,id_pelajar,sesi,kursus,no_tel,email) VALUES ('','$nama_pelajar','$ic_pelajar',
    '$id_pelajar','$sesi','$kursus','$no_tel','$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }

if($sesi=="jun_15")
    {


//assuming you have Jun15 table in your database with same field as your 
//original insert query in the question
        $query = "INSERT INTO  Jun15(id, nama_pelajar,ic_pelajar,id_pelajar,sesi,kursus,no_tel,email) VALUES ('','$nama_pelajar','$ic_pelajar',
    '$id_pelajar','$sesi','$kursus','$no_tel','$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    //i am leaving this your query here i dont know why you need it, may be you 
//need it 
    $query = "INSERT INTO register_jun14 ( nama_pelajar,ic_pelajar,id_pelajar,sesi,kursus,no_tel,email) VALUES ('$nama_pelajar','$ic_pelajar',
    '$id_pelajar','$sesi','$kursus','$no_tel','$email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

you can write further if statement according to your value in drop down menu
You can add as many if condition you want in order to achieve your goal for drop down menu, why you are running select query i have no idea.

Comment: could you please give me your email? Hopefully you can help me out. thanks for your concern!

Comment: @amc remember this, this code is pretty vulnerable to sql injection, if you want to learn more about go to this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgogIRji28U&t=38s or google it, wish you luck

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 , thnks a lot